# Double encoding

Tags: web, web-applications, filter, xss, payload

Hello i am working on a website and i found some filters of xss in a First name field and i am very excited to bypass it but now the problem is that i when i use single encoding like:- **aaa%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22x%3Ax%22%20onerror%3Dalert%281%29%3E**

then the response in the source code is **aaa">img src="x:x" onerror=alert(1)>**

**Note:- ", > these two are convert by htmlencoder (like &lt, &gt these are not shown in stack overflow page) and < is escaping by the website**

But when i use double encoding like:- **aaa%2522%253E%253Cimg%2520src%253D%2522x%253Ax%2522%2520onerror%253Dalert%25281%2529%253E**

It simply converts it into the single encoding like:- **aaa%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22x%3Ax%22%20onerror%3Dalert%281%29%3E**

Sometimes i thought it is not vulnerable So i need your point of view,

But if it is vulnerable then what Payload should i try?

Comment: Its depend, what is the html tag where you are trying to inject the XSS. But if "<" is escaped, you can't create new HTML tags.

Comment: Do you have a file called `urllib2.py` in the directory you're running that from?

Comment: Don't create files with the same name as python standard library modules. That will cause issues like this.

Comment: @glibdud can you please tell me the solution of this new edited question?

Comment: @Utkarsh: if you want to ask a different question, use the "Ask Question" button to start a new question. Don't edit this one into something different.

Comment: What You think I didn't do?. Actually I am not able to ask question a new question. That is why.

Comment: Okay Can you suggest some edit in it? Or Upvote it, if you can?

Comment: lol it get down, when you edited

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal in the future, you can have better results and answers by making a quick review on the text you wrote. Right now, it's just too much confusing. Also, quick reminder that your post seems to be asking for opinions, and SO is not aimed at that. Try to ask for something more precise, like "How that could be exploited? Could I do something in lines of XXX?"